# Should I run tests for the entire core and contributed modules, or only for the codes I wrote?

Tags: 8, testing

I am planning to integrate unit testing in CI/CD. I wonder what would be the good practice for running.

Should I run tests for the entire core and contributed modules, or only for the codes I wrote?

Comment: only for codes you wrote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole point of doing unit testing is verifying code functionality and preventing regression bugs on new code changes. Unless you're working on some development branch (i.e. not a release), running 3rd party vendor (core, contrib modules) unit tests is redundant; you should write unit tests for code that you're maintaining and trying to keep reliable and bug free.

Comment: How can I configure it to run for specific folder only?

Comment: Look up the documentation for PHPUnit (general PHP questions are off topic here). You can tell it how to target specific dirs.